# How to let ul re-size by window width change when its with nowrap property

Tags: css, html-lists, nowrap

As my title write, now I have a menu made by ul li, I won't let the menu break due to window is too narrow. But once it is attached "nowrap" property, it won't re-size with windows anymore, how can I make it is not only nowrap but no-break line.

```
<ul class="parallMenu">
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
</ul>



.parallMenu{
   list-style:none;
   margin-left:0;
   padding-left:0;
   text-decoration:none;
   white-space:npwrap;
   width:100%;
}

.parallMenu li{
   width:120px;
   min-width:30px;
   display:inline-block;

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

```
$(".parallMenu").toggleClass("nowrap");

.nowrap
{
  width: 500px !important; /*(fixed value)*/;
}
```

same  goes for the other properties

OR

```
<ul id="MyMenu" class="parallMenu wrap"></ul>
$("#MyMenu").toggleClass("wrap");
$("#MyMenu").toggleClass("nowrap");

.wrap
{
  white-space :wrap;
}
.nowrap
{
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and have different class defining differet stuff for u.

**EDITED:**

Please use CSS media screen if there is no script.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
   .parallMenu
   {
      white-space:nowrap;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry for misunderstanding. Use @media (min-width: 768px) { } like this to specify what you want in smaller screen.

Comment: As I understand, is this for plus "white-space:nowrap" if window width less than 768px? But I want width can be flex if it less than 768px, is it the same?

Comment: well, you can keep width as 100%, and just write no-wrap for the boxes. If the window is less than 768px i.e. Or depend on your defined media screen. You can also have a totally different css set for this class once size is less than 768px